# oracle database how to convert consecutive number to date

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

the following query output a consecutive number of the day from a date, for this example the number 2415021:

```
SELECT
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01.01.2101', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'j'))
FROM DUAL
```

how i can convert it back to a date with desired format? i can't find anything for this.

i have already tried different variations fo to_date but nothing runs.

please note it is not a number like 20230101 that i want convert to '2023/01/01'
it is a consecutive number.

Comment: Dates in Oracle have no internal format; they are stored as binary.  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: want to generate a date list with level and convert the number to different date formats like ''DD.MM.YY' and 'DD-MM-YYYY' and others

Comment: Then use a date column along with `TO_CHAR()` to generate the formats you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'j'` [date format element](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-22F2B830-261E-4BF0-91FB-6A1DAFC6D0A3) is:

> Julian day; the number of days since January 1, 4712 BC. Number specified with J must be integers.

You can convert back to a date with the same element:

```
SELECT
  TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(2488435), 'j')
FROM DUAL
```

| TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(2488435),'J') |
| --- |
| 01-JAN-01 |

That gives you a value with a DATE data type. That has an internal binary representation, and does not have any inherent human-readable format. Your client generally decides how to display the internal representation, often using NLS settings, e.g.:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

```
SELECT
  TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(2488435), 'j')
FROM DUAL
```

| TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(2488435),'J') |
| --- |
| 2101-01-01 00:00:00 |

If you want a *string* value in a specific format then explicitly convert it:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(2488435), 'j'), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
FROM DUAL
```

| TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(2488435),'J'),'DD.MM.YYYY') |
| --- |
| 01.01.2101 |

Or for your example number, which doesn't match the date in your code:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(2415021), 'j'), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
FROM DUAL
```

| TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(2415021),'J'),'DD.MM.YYYY') |
| --- |
| 01.01.1900 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X9szKjAz)

But don't store or pass around dates formatted as strings, or as numbers; store and use them as dates, and only format them for final display or an external call (e.g. formatting in ISO format in JSON API call etc.) where a string is required.